# Understanding Amazon AWS usage data

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, usage

I love Amazon AWS, but I'm tearing my hair out over the obscure usage data they give you.  All they seem to have is either an extremely high level summary that just shows you your total monthly cost for each service, or a very hard to read spreadsheet that gives you very detailed usage data but leaves out really obvious things like the cost of each line item (it only shows you the amount of usage, so you have to go and find the rate for each service separately and then multiply rate x usage to get the cost).

Does anybody know of any tools or services that give you better insight into AWS usage data, e.g. total bandwidth cost in and out of AWS per day, or EC2 instance cost per day per instance ?   Ideally I'd like to be able to pull the data programatically, so that I don't have to download a spreadsheet and massage it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately they don't do a whole lot of analysis for you, if you want any information more detailed than their monthly cost summary, you're going to have to write your own scripts to process the raw data they give you. You can download it in several formats, so it's pretty easy to process, you just have to decide what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.  When I started using Amazon AWS S3, I also had the same situation.  One thing that you should do, is to enable access logs on the S3 bucket that you want more details.  Then you can download the logs with AWStat or any other log analyzer tool and check the details that you are interested.

One thing to be aware is that the logs are store in the bucket and they constitute actual usage.

thanks and I hope this helps.

Geo

Comment: Thanks - I'll definitely do that for my S3 access, but it doesn't really help with general bandwidth usage or EC2 instance uptime.

Comment: For that you need to access the EC2 cloud watch feature.  There is a good post in my blog: http://blog.readytocloud.com/search/label/Cloud%20Watch